# R WGCNA error code

Tags: r, wgcna

I am using WGCNA to identify Consensus modules. I get a warning message when completing the following step:

> Call the network topology analysis function for each set in turn

Warning:

```
Warning message: executing %dopar% sequentially: no parallel backend registered
```

Does anyone no what this error code means as I cannot plot the scale free analysis, with soft thresholding.

Thank you

`powers = c(seq(4,10, by=1), seq(12,20, by=2))
powerTables = vector(mode= "list", length = nSets)
for( set in 1:nSets)
powerTables[[set]] = list(data=pickSoftThreshold(multiExpr[[set]]$data, powerVector= powers,
verbose =2)[[2]])`

Comment: Please add your code giving the error and especially the packages you have loaded.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you forgot to load (or install) the `doParallel` package as the <strike>error</strike> warning message is complaining about the lack of a parallel backend. `library("doParallel")` should do the trick.

Comment: Thank you, I have tried this.. but still getting same error message. Packages I installed now are; edgeR, limma, doParallel, WGCNA

Answer (score 1):

What you see is a warning, not an error. Your calculation will run fine, just slower. Unless you see other errors, you should be able to complete all steps of the analysis.